# Пытаюсь выучит ассемблер. Кое-что не особо понятно

Tags: ассемблер

Взял пример из книги (Олега Калашникова "Ассемблер это просто"), который записывает символ в видео буфер DOS по адресу `B800h` и смещению 0 (Код должен выводить ASCII символ смайлика в углу текстового экрана). Сассемблировал код в FASM. (Естественно изменив его под синтаксис FASM)

Вот код:

```
use16
org 100h
mov ax, 0B800h
mov es, ax
mov di, 0h

mov ah, 31
mov al, 1
mov [es:di], ax

mov ah, 10h
int 16h

int 20h
```

Если я обращаюсь к нулевому смещению по адресу `B800`, то значит, обращение прямо идет на этот же адрес.

Но попробовав заменить `mov [es:di], ax` на это: `mov [0B800], ax`. У меня символ не появился, как с первым кодом. Почему так?

Answer (score 6):

Адрес рассчитывается не как сумма регистра сегмента + смещение, а регистр сегмента*16 (сдвинуть на 4 бита влево) и только потом добавить смещение.

Конструкция `mov [0B800], ax` работать не будет, потому что нужно задать немного другой адрес `mov [0B8000], ax`, но на 16 битном регистре задать 20 бит нельзя...

Еще раз `mov [es:di], ax` записывает по адресу `es*16+di`, а не `es+di`.

Comment: *регистр смещения* => "регистр сегмента" :)

Comment: ага, пальцы иногда промазывают

Comment: *Конструкция mov [0B800], ax работать не будет* => будет работать, но не так, как ожидается. Sorry, была неделя в режиме педанта, выползать непросто :)

Comment: "не будет работать" имеет два значения. Не будет компилироваться и не будет делать то, что от нее ожидают

Answer (score 0):

```
 mov [0B800], ax
```

Это - запись по смещению 0B800h в текущем сегменте данных. То есть на что указывает DS, туда и пишется.

> use16

А оно точно вам надо? :-)